# Getting wrong output in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Attendance Table Sample Data -

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| EnrollmentNo | SubjectCode |   Date    | Attendance | CourseCode |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| DDU-140/12   | CSHT101     | 1/9/2018  |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-140/12   | CSHT101     | 1/10/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-140/12   | CSHT101     | 1/11/2018 |          2 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT101     | 1/9/2018  |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT101     | 1/10/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT101     | 1/11/2018 |          0 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT102     | 1/11/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT102     | 1/14/2018 |          2 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT101     | 1/9/2018  |          2 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT101     | 1/10/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT101     | 1/11/2018 |          0 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT102     | 1/11/2018 |          1 | BSCCS      |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT102     | 1/14/2018 |          0 | BSCCS      |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Student Table Sample Data -

```
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| EnrollmentNo | RollNO | CollegeCode | CourseCode | Year |
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
| DDU-140/12   |     22 | DDUC        | BSCCS      | 2012 |
| DDU-286/12   |     15 | DDUC        | BSCCS      | 2012 |
| DDU-320/12   |     38 | DDUC        | BSCCS      | 2012 |
+--------------+--------+-------------+------------+------+
```

StudentSubject Table Sample Data -

```
+--------------+-------------+
| EnrollmentNo | SubjectCode |
+--------------+-------------+
| DDU-140/12   | CSHT101     |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT101     |
| DDU-286/12   | CSHT102     |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT101     |
| DDU-320/12   | CSHT102     |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Subject Table Sample Data -

```
+-------------+---------------------------+
| SubjectCode |        SubjectName        |
+-------------+---------------------------+
| CSHP101     | Software Lab based on 101 |
| CSHT101     | Programming Fundamentals  |
| CSHT102     | Discrete Structures       |
+-------------+---------------------------+
```

Output -

[image: Output]

Wrong output is displaying with parameters -

```
@enrollno = 'DDU-320/12',
@startdate = '1/9/2018',
@enddate = '1/11/2018'
```

As 2,1,0 and NA,NA,1 should be displayed instead 2,1,1 and 2,1,1 is displaying.

Couldn't point out the mistake I am making. Can somebody take a look ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ATTENDANCE_REPORT_FOR_STUDENT
@enrollno varchar(10),
@startdate DATE,  
@enddate DATE

AS BEGIN

DECLARE @query as varchar(MAX);

with cte (startdate) as 
(
    select @startdate startdate
    union all 
    select dateadd(DD, 1, startdate) 
    from cte
    where startdate < @enddate
)

select @query = coalesce(@query, '') + 
              N',coalesce(MAX(CASE when A.[Date] = ''' + 
              cast(cte.startdate as nvarchar(20)) + 
              N''' THEN Convert(varchar(10),A.[Attendance]) end), ''NA'') ' + 
              quotename(convert(char(6), cte.startdate,106))
from cte
where datename(weekday, cte.startdate) <> 'Sunday';

set @query = 'Select Concat(S.SubjectCode,'' '',S.SubjectName) Subject' + @query + '
              from Attendance A, Student St, StudentSubject SS, Subject S
              where A.EnrollmentNo=St.EnrollmentNo and St.EnrollmentNo=SS.EnrollmentNo and SS.SubjectCode=S.SubjectCode and St.EnrollmentNo =''' + @enrollno + '''
              Group By S.SubjectName,S.SubjectCode';


Execute (@query)
END
```

Comment: add sample data as text in table format.. do not use images to show the sample data nobody can use it for testing

Comment: What is the datatype of `Attendance.Date`

Comment: Attendance.Date - date and
Attendance.Attendance - numeric

Comment: Query 
looks fine to me.. other than the records you have shown, I believe you have some more records for the `EnrollmentNo : DDU-320/12`. Run this query and see `select * from Attendance where EnrollmentNo = 'DDU-320/12'`

Comment: Nope. Showed you the full table. Don't have more than 4 records for 'DDU-320/12'.

Comment: Check this http://rextester.com/KNIG32974 it works as expected

Comment: Yes, when I removed the join with Student and StudentSubject, it worked fine. Something wrong with the join then.

Comment: I don't understand how joins could cause problem here. Inside the case statement both `Date` and `Attendance` is picked from `Attendance` table, so if join conditions are wrong then either records should get filtered or duplicate records should be populated how come case statement will have an impact

Comment: That I am also not able to understand but removing these Student St, StudentSubject SS, giving the correct output.

Comment: By looking at your query, in `join` you don't need to those two tables in first place.Post the sample data of other 3 tables as well. I will try to check

Comment: Yes, I realized that I don't need to join Student and StudentSubject.

Comment: Sample Data updated incase you want to look into the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a join condition, `Attendance` table needs to be joined with `SubjectCode` as well. Due to the missing condition, it is picking the dates from both the `SubjectCodes`.

```
set @query = '
SELECT Concat(S.SubjectCode, '' '', S.SubjectName) Subject
       '+ @query +'
FROM   Attendance A
       INNER JOIN Student St
               ON A.EnrollmentNo = St.EnrollmentNo
       INNER JOIN StudentSubject SS
               ON St.EnrollmentNo = SS.EnrollmentNo
                  AND a.SubjectCode = ss.SubjectCode --here
       INNER JOIN Subject S
               ON SS.SubjectCode = S.SubjectCode
WHERE  St.EnrollmentNo =''' + @enrollno + '''
GROUP  BY S.SubjectName,
          S.SubjectCode'

Execute (@query)
```

Also start using `INNER JOIN` syntax over the old style comma separated joins. Keep the join conditions in `ON` clause and filters in `Where` clause.

Having said that all, you don't need those two tables in first place according to your expected result